# One liner template type changer

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I'm sorry for the title, I don't know how to call it...

I'm trying to make a one liner of the *caller()* function (C++20).

```
template <typename T>
void func() {
    std::cerr << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

void caller(const int &_i) {
    switch(_i) {
        case 1:
            func<uint8_t>();
            break;
        case 2:
            func<uint16_t>();
            break;
        case 3:
            func<uint32_t>();
            break;
        case 4:
            func<uint64_t>();
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    caller(1);
    caller(2);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried with *struct helper* but it seems this case do not fit.
I also tried a different approach with *caller<i>()* and the use of std::conditional_t, but did not find how to use it in this specific case.

```
template <size_t ID>
void func() {
    using T = std::conditional_t<ID==0, uint8_t, [...]>;
    std::cerr << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Is there multiple ways to do this, and if so, which are they?

Comment: line breaks do not matter. You can remove them without changing the meaning of the code. If you want to map from a runtime value to a type you need to write that mapping somehow. Your `caller` looks ok

Comment: is `i` actually a runtime value? `caller` suggests yes, but in your last snippet it looks like no.

Comment: Did you try `func<1>(); func<2>();`?

Comment: If you want `caller` to be able to be called with a run time value then what you have is about as good as you can get.  There are ways to make the code a little shorter but they all come with a performance cost.

Comment: Templates aren't usually don't help much when you have to make runtime decissions.

Comment: its also unclear what is wrong with the `std::conditional` approach. Should work. If you post the complete code we could help

Comment: Indeed it was unclear: I tried two different approaches, I edited my post.  I'm not concerned about if it's decided at runtime or not, even if it should be better not to.

Comment: `caller<i>()` cannot be used with non `constexpr` `i` (and parameters of functions are never `constexpr`).

Comment: @Agathe_DVY You need to pick if you want this to work at run time or not because the way to do it at compile time is not compatible with the way to do it at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can provide the value to caller at compile time, you can do something like this:

```
template<std::size_t>
struct int_type_id;

template<>
struct int_type_id<0> { using type = std::uint8_t; };

template<>
struct int_type_id<1> { using type = std::uint16_t; };

template<>
struct int_type_id<2> { using type = std::uint32_t; };

template<>
struct int_type_id<3> { using type = std::uint64_t; };

template <std::size_t ID>
void caller() {
    using T = typename int_type_id<ID>::type;
    func<T>();
    // you can reduce that to a one liner:
    // func<typename int_type_id<ID>::type>();
}
```

A true one liner for that could be using `std::tuple` and `std::tuple_element_t`:

```
template <std::size_t ID>
void caller() {
    using T = std::tuple_element_t<
        ID, std::tuple<std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>
    >;
    func<T>();
}
```

Then call it like that:

```
int main() {
    caller<1>();
    caller<2>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, thank you.

Comment: FWIW you can make this much shorter using a `std::tuple` map a index to a type: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/225fd65021085b59

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh pretty neat!

Answer (score 3):

This is as close as I can get to caller being a branchless one liner
(use with care, no out of bound checks)

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void func() 
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
}

static constexpr std::array<void(*)(), 4> funcs
{
    func<std::uint8_t>,
    func<std::uint16_t>,
    func<std::uint32_t>,
    func<std::uint64_t>
};
    
void caller(const std::size_t index)
{
    funcs[index]();
}

int main()
{
    caller(1ul);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to handle out of bounds access.  In the OP's code nothing happens, with this, UB happens.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's why I have the warning there :)
But should be as easy as `if ( index > 3ul ) return;` as first line of the function.

Comment: or [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) access.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes I like that better

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::variant` and `std::type_identity` to do type dispatch.

```cpp
using VType = std::variant<std::type_identity<uint8_t>,
                           std::type_identity<uint16_t>,
                           std::type_identity<uint32_t>,
                           std::type_identity<uint64_t>>;

static const std::unordered_map<int, VType> dispatcher = {
    {1, std::type_identity<uint8_t>{}},
    {2, std::type_identity<uint16_t>{}},
    {3, std::type_identity<uint32_t>{}},
    {4, std::type_identity<uint64_t>{}},
};

void caller(const int &_i) {
    return std::visit([&](auto v){
        func<typename decltype(v)::type>();
    }, dispatcher.at(_i));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mbh6KjWz4)

Disclaimer: Pay attention to run-time performance if you care about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class...Ts>
using type_venum_t = std::variant< std::type_identity<Ts>... >;

template<auto...Is>
using venum_t = std::variant< std::integral_constant<decltype(Is),Is>... >;

template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr venum_t<Is...> index( std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::size_t I )
{
  venum_t<Is...> table[] = {
    std::integral_constant<decltype(Is),Is>{}...
  };
  return table[I];
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto index( std::size_t I ) {
  return index(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, I );
}

using types = type_venum_t<uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t>;

void caller( const int& i ) {
  // get a compile-time evaluable value from 0 to 3 inclusive:
  auto idx = index<4>( i-1 );
  // evaluate it:
  std::visit([](auto I) {
    func< typename std::variant_alternative_t<I, types>::type >();
  }, idx);
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/99zPKoqxf).

This generalizes pretty easily.